# Inegrating differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to integrate these differential equations:

1) $ t( y^{2}-1 )dt+y( t^{2}-1 )dy=0  $

2) $ 2 \sqrt{t}y'= \sqrt{1- y^{2} }$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: for your first equation write
$$\frac{t}{t^2-1}dt=-\frac{y}{y^2-1}dy$$
and for your second equation write
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

the first can be written as

$$\frac { 2tdt }{  1-t^2}=\frac { 2ydy }{ y^2-1 }$$

which can be integrated as

$$-\ln (|t^2-1|)=\ln (|y^2-1|)+C $$,